# Why does this armature move like it has IK with no bone constraints?

Tags: rigging

I am attempting to study an armature to understand how it was rigged, and I'm having trouble understanding why the bones move like they have IK when there are no constraints on the bones.

There is a shoulder bone, an upper arm bone, a lower arm bone, and a hand bone. When I move any of these bones, all of them move like they have IK on them, but there are no bone constraints. A dotted yellow/orange line appears and connects from the bone I am actively moving to the shoulder bone, which I know has something to do with it, but I have been googling what that is to very little success.

Here are the bones at rest position:

[image: Image of bones at rest position]

Here are the bones when I move the upper arm bone, keep in mind I can move any of the four bones and get the same bendy arm result.

[image: Images of bones bending like they have IK]

None of these bones have constraints.

What is causing the bones to move like this? Is there a setting somewhere that I'm missing?

EDIT: I added the blend file

[image]

Comment: can you share the blend file? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  Often things like this are done by having other bones on hidden bone layers that implement the constraints, but it's hard to tell without looking at the rig.

Comment: @MartyFouts I added the blend file, thanks for the how to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *N panel > Tool > Pose Options*, *Auto IK* is enabled:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!